# Write a paragraph indentation into a text file

Tags: python-3.x, with-statement

Its simple ( i think), but yet i can't find how to do it anywere. I Just need to append new phrases to a  text file, but each new append in a new paragraph.

Ex output :

**instead of :** first phrase second phrase third phrase.

**write it this way :**

first phrase

second phrase

third phrase

here's my code :

```
nm = 'name'
while nm != 'done' :
    nm = str(input('name : '))
    pos = str(input('%s ocupation : ' %(nm)))
    with open("Output.txt", "a") as fd:
        fd.write('%s = irmaos("%s","%s" )' % (nm, pos, nm))
```

Comment: You need to add a line feed (`\n`)) at the point you want a line break.

Comment: Thanks ! so simple